# AVFoundation: Audio from AVAudioPlayer picked up during recording

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, avfoundation

I am writing an app that plays an audio track for the user to listen to whilst recording from the camera and microphone (using headphones).

The audio track is played using AVAudioPlayer.
The camera/microphone is recorded using AVCaptureSession.
The output uses AVCaptureMovieFileOutput.

It all works perfectly on an iPhone 5 but my iPad 4 experiences an odd side effect. When playing back the recording from the iPad you can hear the audio track as if it has also been recorded. This is all done whilst using headphones and the audio is too quiet to be picked up by the microphone.

When testing on the iPhone only the audio from the mic is recorded, as expected. Both use the same code. Any ideas would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is having the same problem. I couldn't solve it. Instead I used the setPreferredDataSource:error: method in AVAudioSession to use the device microphone instead of the one on the headset.